# Diffrence in cc_library and cc_binary?

Tags: bazel

Diffrence in cc_library and cc_binary and filegroup, and what are usecases of each.

**cc_library**-create library from other libarary including its dependencies. when bazel builds it'll create single library out of it. basically group of files under one library and can be further used as dependency for other library or binary.

**CC_binary** is binary file generated from bazel build, from src file and its header/dependency. As it is binary, it can't b used as dependency for other, but is direct executable.

But is there more detail on difference?,what usecase that can apply on each, but can't b used on other. how cc_library is different from filegroup? filegroup will b just group, it can't be used as dependency?

Comment: This is a very common concept in computer languages.  You might search for the terms.  A binary is an application that can be executed by itself.  A library is a collection of code that can be referenced by other programs.

Answer (score 0):

A `cc_binary(name = "target_name" ...` can be executed via `bazel run //:target_name`. A `cc_library` is not executable.

A binary is something that can be executed - a library cannot be executed. This works similar for other rules, e.g. `go_binary`/`go_library`, `java_binary`/`java_library`, `python_binary`/`python_library`, etc.

Comment: and filegroup is just collection of files..right?